# Vue.JS and figures/captions

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm working on my new website design and decided to incorporate Vue.JS which I know very little about but am learning as I redesign my website.

I am using a Vue app to load different pages on my site.
I am also using it to load the image gallery, so I have all my images placed into an array in the app and they load just fine into the HTML.

I decided to use `figures` and want to place a caption beneath each image.

What I'm trying to do is place the `figcaption` text in the vue app, as part of the image array and have it load each text that belongs with each image.

this is the code i have for the html:

```html
<div id="images" class="gallery content" v-if="gallery" v-for='img in imgs'>
    <figure>
        <img class="gallery-img" id="img.id" :src="img.url" :alt="img.alt" v-on:click="showModal">
        <figcaption> a caption </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

the "a caption" is just a place taker right now so i can see what it looks like on the site but i want that replaced with the actual caption which would be set in the vue app which is below.

js:

```js
<script>
    const test = Vue.createApp({
        data(){
            return{
                home: true,
                gallery: false,
                store: false,
                about: false,
                imgs: [
                    { url: 'images\\wood_gallery\\pens\\pen0.jpeg', id: 'pen0', alt: 'an image', caption: 'Pen kit: Skeleton key \n Wood: unknown' },
```

.... rest of the vue app code which is fine and works so not necessary to show.

Question: Can I do it this way and how do I access that 'caption' portion of text and put it into the html as text?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `img.caption` in the figure tag to display the caption content.

```
<figure>
    <img class="gallery-img" id="img.id" :src="img.url" :alt="img.alt" v-on:click="showModal">
    <figcaption>{{ img.caption }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works fine.

```
        <div id="images" class="gallery content" v-if="gallery" v-for='img in imgs'>
            <figure>
                <img class="gallery-img" id="img.id" :src="img.url" :alt="img.alt" v-on:click="showModal">
                <figcaption v-html=“caption”></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
```

```
            const test = Vue.createApp({
                data(){
                    return{
                        home: true,
                        gallery: false,
                        store: false,
                        about: false,
                        caption:"<h1>hi</h1>",
                        imgs: [
                            { url: 'images\\wood_gallery\\pens\\pen0.jpeg', id: 'pen0', alt: 'an image', caption: 'Pen kit: Skeleton key \n Wood: unknown' },
```